# Is it possible to add style sheet only to a content page?

Tags: asp.net, css, content-pages

In a asp.net webforms project, I need to add external style sheet only to content page,

If I put css link after the `<%@ Page>` declaration it gives an error saying

```
Error   103 Validation (XHTML 1.0 Transitional): Content is not supported outside 'script' or 'asp:content' regions.
```

If I put it inside `<asp:Content>` tag error is

```
Error   104 Cannot switch views: Validation (XHTML 1.0 Transitional): Element 'link' cannot be nested within element 'td'.
```

Is it possible to add a style sheet only to content page?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should create a place holder in the head section in master page. Then in the content page, if you want to include js, css, ... put on this place holder, unless keep it empty.